# sun.security.x509.X509CertImpl cannot be cast to iaik.x509.X509Certificate

Tags: java, x509certificate, keystore, entrust, iaik-jce

i extracted a certificate from a JKS keystore and attempted to cast it to iaik.x509.X509Certificate. it failed with sun.security.x509.X509CertImpl cannot be cast to iaik.x509.X509Certificate.
is there a way to write it to iaik.x509.X509Certificate manually?
code snippet -

```
        KeyStore trustStore = KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.getDefaultType());
        FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(keystorePath);
        char[] keyPasswordChars = keyPassword == null ? new char[0] : keyPassword.toCharArray();
        try {
                trustStore.load(in, keyPasswordChars);
        } finally   {
                in.close();
        }
        Certificate cert = trustStore.getCertificate(alias);
        if (cert != null) {
            iaik.x509.X509Certificate  x509 = (iaik.x509.X509Certificate) cert;
            return x509;
        }
```

iaik.x509.X509Certificate is from Entrust - enttoolkit.jar

Comment: Why? You shouldn't be using either of these classes directly, and you will certainly never get an IAIK certificate object directly from a Java keystore file via the Java `KeyStore` API. You should be using `java.security.cert.X509Certificate` or possibly even `java.security.cert.Certificate`, whatever the `KeyStore` API actually returns.

Comment: Like user207421 pointed out, do you need the iaik certificate object for any specific reason?

Comment: yes, iaik object is needed because the entrust toolkit has a CertVerifier class that accepts only iaik.X509 certificate. my certificate was saved into the keystoe using java.security.cert.Certificate but now have to pass iaik.x509.X509Certificate to the CertVerifier method. I will explore saving the certificate to keystore as iaik.x509.X509Certificate.

Comment: Why? The only reason to use IAIK at all is if you have not a JKS keystore but an HSM, for which you have a PKCS#11 (or whatever it is) DLL, and which you want to access it in Java via IAIK.